# Jquery animate sliding menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate

I am building a web app with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) which has a slide out menu like a Facebook app. I have the menu working well but I would like to add a bounce effect when it slides out.

Here is what i have:

```
$("a.showMenu").click(function() {
    if (menuStatus != true) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            left: 250,
        }, 400, function() {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            left: 0,
        }, 300, function() {
            menuStatus = false
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

My jQuery skills are very limited. Would anybody be able to help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) from George McGinley Smith.

Try this example (untested):

```
$("a.showMenu").click(function(){
    if(menuStatus != true){             
    $(".ui-page-active").animate({
        left: 250,
      }, 400, 'easeOutBounce', function(){menuStatus = true});
      return false;
      } else {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
        left: 0,
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
        return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: The example stops it working completely. I will take a look at the plugin.

Comment: You'll need to include jQuery UI or the plugin mentioned in the answer to make it work, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qyWm/) ..

Comment: These are both great but for some reason I cant get them to work with what I have. Here is what I'm playing about with http://m.filmrev.me//m/view/demo/build/pull_11.html

Comment: **500** - "Internal Server Error"

Comment: No problem! I think you just need to insert the code from [my first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922874/1250044) into your site.

Here is the implemented script into your project: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vhqdQ/1/)